# How do you split a list by space in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file-processing

How do you split a list by space? With the code below, it reads a file with 4 lines of 7 numbers separated by spaces. When it takes the file and then splits it, it splits it by number so if i print item[0], 5 will print instead of 50. here is the code

```
def main():
    filename = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
    infile = open(filename, "r")
    for i in range(4):
        data = infile.readline()
        print(data)
        item = data.split()
        print(data[0])

main()
```

the file looks like this

50 60 15 100 60 15 40 /n
100 145 20 150 145 20 45 /n
50 245 25 120 245 25 50 /n
100 360 30 180 360 30 55 /n

Comment: read the documentation of `.split()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  You have the search terms, but didn't follow the posting guidelines.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: Durr. `item[0]` is the first entry in the result list of the split. `data[0]`is the first character of the string you are splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Split takes as argument the character you want to split your string with.

I invite you to read the documentation of methods you are using. :)

EDIT : By the way, readline returns a **string**, not a **list **.
However, split does return a list.

Comment: Well, you should do that first, from `split()` docs: "If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator"

Comment: Oh lol, thanks mate.
I guess I learned a lesson today. Never take anything for granted. :

Comment: Well, yes, but your answer doesn't answer the question/problem the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

```
import nltk

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(TextInTheFile)
```

Try this once you have opened that file.

> TextInTheFile is a variable

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot wrong with what you are doing, except that you are printing the wrong thing.

Instead of

```
print(data[0])
```

use

```
print(item[0])
```

`data[0]` is the first character of the string you read from file. You split this string into a variable called `item` so that's what you should print.